# Div is overlaping the one below even though the previous did's height is set to auto

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the class "work" that is overlaping another div below it named "about" even though both of them have height set to auto. Keep in mind that I'm writing for a screen size of 480px using Media Queries. Check the picture to see what I'm talking about.[The button is overlaping onto the div below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0huN.png)

```css
.work {
  max-height: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  text-align: center;
}

.work .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 5% 5%;
}

.work img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid GhostWhite;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.work button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid GhostWhite;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.work button a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* About me */

.about {
  background-color: #000000;
  #ffffff;
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  text-align: center;
}

.about .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>MY WORK</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="gallery">
      <img id="image-1" src="file:///C:/Users/Nelson/Desktop/Portfolio/Images/taduuda-72915.jpg">
      <button><a href="#">Learn More</a></button>
    </div>


    <div class="gallery">
      <img id="image-2" src="file:///C:/Users/Nelson/Desktop/Portfolio/Images/taduuda-72915.jpg">
      <button><a href="#">Learn More</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- About Me -->

<div class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed posuere lacinia urna vel dapibus. Suspendisse nec porttitor ipsum. Etiam lorem dolor, pulvinar eu magna ac, lobortis scelerisque nulla. Aenean vel fringilla neque, at porta risus. Praesent
      vitae congue dolor. Morbi pharetra egestas lacinia. Nam luctus dictum aliquam. Vivamus vestibulum egestas odio, ut lacinia justo. Nullam vulputate blandit efficitur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem comes down to how you are using `float` (as noted in @athi's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added

```
.about {
  clear: both;
}

and

.work {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

Since the button was floated to the left, it should be cleared for `.about`.

```css
.work {
  max-height: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.work .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 5% 5%;
}

.work img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid GhostWhite;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.work button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid GhostWhite;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.work button a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* About me */

.about {
  background-color: #000000;
  #ffffff;
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

.about .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>MY WORK</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="gallery">
      <img id="image-1" src="file:///C:/Users/Nelson/Desktop/Portfolio/Images/taduuda-72915.jpg">
      <button><a href="#">Learn More</a></button>
    </div>


    <div class="gallery">
      <img id="image-2" src="file:///C:/Users/Nelson/Desktop/Portfolio/Images/taduuda-72915.jpg">
      <button><a href="#">Learn More</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- About Me -->

<div class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed posuere lacinia urna vel dapibus. Suspendisse nec porttitor ipsum. Etiam lorem dolor, pulvinar eu magna ac, lobortis scelerisque nulla. Aenean vel fringilla neque, at porta risus. Praesent
      vitae congue dolor. Morbi pharetra egestas lacinia. Nam luctus dictum aliquam. Vivamus vestibulum egestas odio, ut lacinia justo. Nullam vulputate blandit efficitur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the float present in .gallery

```
.gallery:after {
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

For more about clearing floats
reference
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-4

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how floats *don't* work and the ways you can force them to work *with* you. Explanations are in the code and its comments. Also, here's a jsFiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/xdgLLucj/

```css
.parent {
  background: #f06;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.parent .child {
  background: pink;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.parent.natural {
  /* natural */
}

.parent.child-floated .child {
  float: left;
  /* child is in a different flow */
  /* parent is confused... */
}

.parent.both-floated, .parent.both-floated .child {
  float: left;
  /* but now what about the parent's parent... */
  /* + no longer 100% width */
}

.parent.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* causes edge case problems in old browsers */
  /* still an issue? no... */
  /* + no longer 100% width */
  width: 100%;
}
.parent.overflow-hidden .child {
  float: left;
}

/* you can use this to 'clear floats' - refered to generally as a 'clear-fix' (hack) */
.clear-floats:after {
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
} /* added to markup */
.parent.clear-floats .child {
  float: left;
}

/* also... read about this when you start running into padding problems and unexpected widths:  https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
```

```html
<div class="parent natural">
  parent: natural
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>

<div class="parent child-floated">
  parent: just the child floated
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>

<div class="parent both-floated">
  parent: both floated
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>

<div class="parent overflow-hidden">
  parent: overflow: hidden
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>

<div class="parent clear-floats">
  parent: clear-floats<br>
  this is the best option - unless you want to use flexbox - where you can leave this kind of thing behind : )
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```